# Family of diffeomorphisms on the boundary of the disk to itself that fixes 3 distinct points

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, complex-analysis

For context, I'm currently studying Sullivan's proof to the No-Wandering Domains Theorem. In his arc argument, he makes use of the real analytic family of diffeomorphisms of $\partial \mathbb{D}$ to itself that fixes three distinct points.

I assume this family has infinite dimension, but I am a little unsure of the form this family must take, and why exactly it is infinitely dimensional.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Infinite dimensional as a what? Topological space? Some kind of manifold? What is the relevant definition of dimension, or even of being infinite dimensional?